# Scikit clustering always give one point cluster

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm using Scikit clustering kmeans on my dataset. I'm using 6 clusters and everything seems fine:

[image]

However, immediately after the fitting the kmeans, I do a group by on the labels and get the following:

```
Length: 55003, dtype: int64
0  count    23110
1  count        1
2  count    10923
3  count    17949
4  count     1736
5  count     1284
```

I always get that cluster that only has 1 data point. If I save the model and predict the data again on the model, the predictions also have one data point on it's own. What's up with that? Is it a bug with sci-kit?

Comment: This is odd, are you able to post your data? also what version numpy, sklearn are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It was one outlier. I removed it from my data and the groups are appropriate now.